# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Q4' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    PRE_DTR nvarchar(20),
   TR_PRE_DTR nvarchar(20)
); 


INSERT INTO Persons(PRE_DTR, TR_PRE_DTR) 
VALUES ('10.12.2014', '');

INSERT INTO Persons(PRE_DTR, TR_PRE_DTR) 
VALUES ('10.12.2014', '');


SELECT
   PRE_DTR,
   CASE
      WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, PRE_DTR) IN (10, 11, 12) 
        THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), DATEPART(MONTH, PRE_DTR) + 'Q4') 
   END AS TR_PRE_DTR
FROM
   Persons
```

When I run this query I 'm getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Q4' to data type int.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Your syntax says "SQL Server" but the question is tagged "MySQL".  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

The operator `+` is overloaded.  When any argument is numeric, it means addition.  When all arguments are strings, it means string concatenation.

`datepart()` returns a number, so you have to convert this to a character value.  Personally, I prefer the function `month()` over `datepart()`, so:

```
select PRE_DTR,
       (case when month(PRE_DTR) IN (10, 11, 12) 
             then convert(nvarchar(20), MONTH(PRE_DTR)) + 'Q4')
        end) AS TR_PRE_DTR
from Persons;
```

Your query was close.  But you were doing the `+` *before* the `convert()`.  Hence the error, because the month was still a number.